# Cumulative subtraction result in the succeeding row in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to find cumulative subtraction of the two columns and display the result in the succeeding row of the tables( rows are in a sorted order). 
**Table 1**

```
ID | Item | Qty1 | Qty2 | Date 
1  | I1   | 10   | 100  | 5-Jul
1  | I1   | 20   | 90   | 6-Jul
1  | I1   | 15   | 70   | 7-Jul 
2  | I2   | 10   | 50   | 5-Jul 
2  | I2   | 50   | 40   | 6-Jul 
2  | I2   | 10   | -10  | 7-Jul
```

ID,Item is the Primary key 
For each ID, Item combination the first value in Qty2 is populated 
For all the succeeding rows Qty2-Qty1 result should be displayed in the next row till the last record. 
The last row's subtraction result is not required

This is the main question.

I have an additional question- 
the row1 of ID,Item combination is populated from a different table(Table2)  having the qty for the same ID,Item combination. Any ways of populating that qty only to the first row in this sorted table?

**Table2**

```
| ID | Item | Qty | 
| 1  | I1   |100  |
| 2  | I2   |50   |
```

These qtys should be copied only to the first row of ID, Item of Table1

Could anyone please help with these queries.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use something like below.

```
with data (ID,Item,Qty1,Qty2,Date1 ) as
(select 1,'I1',10,100,'5-Jul' from dual union all
select 1,'I1',20,90,'6-Jul' from dual union all
select 1,'I1',15,70,'7-Jul' from dual union all
select 2,'I2',10,50,'5-Jul' from dual union all
select 2,'I2',50,40,'6-Jul' from dual union all
select 2,'I2',10,-10,'7-Jul' from dual)
select d.*, 
case when date1=min(date1) over (partition by id,item) then qty2
else Qty2 -  Qty1 end diff_qty
from data d;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9a1b4a6158383504f3ea51b3885d99b5).

For second part, please add an example with data and sample output, as its not very clear.

Comment: Thank you, have added Table2 details. The output is the first row of ID,Item combination of Table1.
Also as per your query, the Diff_qty is displayed in the same row. But I want to put that qty in Qty2 of the succeeding row.

Comment: How about the last record diff, should that be displayed against the ID, item combo for next ID, item?

Comment: Any ways of ignoring the subtraction of the last record ?

Comment: Still not very clear for the last record. Refer updated fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a6e38d254326e89eced10a4c796e4ba). Its putting difference in subsequent ID, item combo row and ignores last record and for first record - uses Qty2 value as diff.

Comment: Sure @pankaj. thanks for the answer, will try once at my end too. Any leads on the second question ?

Comment: For second part are you looking for an update statement from table2 to table1? Also did you checked the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a6e38d254326e89eced10a4c796e4ba) for first part, is that still not what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. An update command

Comment: Refer [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6f8ec61ee241492f5ebb69382ac400a)